# Instance a Python object from another Python file

Tags: python

I am trying to call a Python object inside a Python file, which I will call A.py, from another Python file which I will call B.py.

Inside B, I import that object like:

```
from .A import Object
```

It gives me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "B.py", line 1, in 
>       from .A import Object
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__ main__ .A'; '__ main__' is not a package

I do not understand why it gives me an error. My code is written in Python 3.

Any suggestions? I do not understand other posts around object instances in Python.

Comment: remove `.`  from ocde

Comment: PyCharm says it is an error if I remove the point. Both files are in the same directory.

Comment: Check if `__init__.py` file exists on the directory of A.py

Comment: I do not have any file like that, why should I have an __init__.py?

Comment: @EnriqueGonzález What is the error when you remove `.`?

Comment: @EnriqueGonzález use `from A import object` don;t g for error which ide is showing you, just run and see if you are getting error

Comment: I worked guys, thank you all! It was a Pycharm syntax error as you said, but it works when I run it on terminal